# XPath: find value and return also the path leading there

Tags: xpath, path, parent, ancestor

I would like to find all occurrences of a tag in an XML and return them *with their parent* (or maybe all their ancestors).  I do not want the complete ancestors, though, but just the tag of the parent (or all ancestors).

Example:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
    <d/>
  </b>
  <e>
    <c/>
    <d/>
  </e>
</a>
```

For this I would like to get `<b><c/></b>` and `<e><c/></e>` but they are not supposed to contain the `<d/>` stuff.  (Getting `<a><b><c/></b></a>` and `<a><e><c/></e></a>` would also be okay.)

The tag name `c` is fixed while `b` and `e` are unknown (and therefore shall be part of the search result).

Is there a way to get the path of a search result?

I tried this:

- `//a//c` → But this returns only the two `<c/>`.
- `//a//*[c]` → But this returns the complete `<b>` and `<e>`, together with their contents `<d/>` (which in my case is so large that it clutters the result in a way that I would need to search again in that).

Comment: Wrong tool.  XPath is for selection.   Use XSLT for transformation.

Comment: Yup, I think you might be right.  I just am not sure.  Unfortunately in this case the user who needs this has just a weird XML-GUI allowing XPath for selecting stuff, nothing else.  So using XSLT wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Be sure.  XPath selects, and what you seek isn't available for selection.